# sql ibm db2 trigger after insert multiple table

Tags: sql, triggers

I have three table related in a trigger

> 1) Order_Item -- Recipe_ID, Order_ID, Quantity
>
> 2) Ingredient_Recipe -- Stock_ID, Recipe_ID, Quantity
>
> 3) Stock -- Stock_ID,Balance

Another table related,

> 4) Recipe -- Recipe_ID, Name

Trying to make a trigger that Stock will decrease after Order_Item insert, also based on the quantity in Ingredient_Recipe.

The basic formula is

`Balance (from Stock) - ( Quantity (from Ingredient_recipe ) * Quantity (from Order_Item) )`

I created the trigger

> CREATE TRIGGER Stck_Up
>
> AFTER INSERT ON Order_Item
>
> REFERENCING NEW AS N
>
> FOR EACH ROW mode db2sql
>
> > > > UPDATE Stock
> > > >         SET Balance = (SELECT sum (Stock.Balance - (Quantity *( SELECT Quantity FROM           Ingredient_Recipe
> > > >
> > > > where Ingredient_Recipe.Recipe_ID = Order_Item.Recipe_ID)))
> > > >
> > > > FROM Stock
> > > >         WHERE Stock_ID = N.Stock_ID )
> > > >
> > > > WHERE Stock_ID = N.Stock_ID;

but the error is N.Stock_ID is not valid